# C++, storing & updating a large B+ tree(unclustered) structure ON A FILE

Tags: c++, algorithm, file, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I want to implement a B+ tree structure on C++ as straightforwardly as possible.

However, my software will be managing more than one B+ trees on different time intervals. So what I want to do is to store a B+ tree on a file, update and read it by accessing to that file.

My goal is to approach this problem with a clever way, or to take advantage of any existing open source libraries etc. Is there any library for a similar task? If not, how can I implement it without rewriting some already existing functions (making use of standard b+ tree libraries for example).

Comment: Could you clarify, does there need to be an existing B+ tree library?

Comment: @Samer I just did not want to reinvent the wheel. I am definitely showing effort, its my code after all, but it is good practice to make sure important parts are not already done before.

Comment: @TrygveSkogsholm No its not a necessity. I am editing the question if it gives that impression.

Comment: Don't store a b-tree in a file unless you are writing your own database.  Don't write your own database before reviewing the plethora of available databases.

Comment: I did not realize that I was able to use databases with cpp code, it seems like a pretty viable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Berkeley DB is a popular choice for requirements like that:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB

If you can't stand the license terms, then maybe levelDB or sqlite:

https://github.com/google/leveldb

http://sqlite.org/

Comment: I was thinking SQLite might be good as well. It's already file based with a c++ interface.

I can't think of any easier way to store complicated dynamic data like this.

Comment: If the interface works well for you, then it's probably a good choice.  It's very easy to integrate into your existing code

Comment: I did not know that I was able to use DB functions for this purpose. How does this work exactly, is it like a library that I just include it and use its functions? Or should I also install sql etc?

Comment: 'sql' isn't something you can install. It's a standard just like c++.

You can install c++ compilers.

Same with SQL, you can install SQL engines and if they follow the spec you will be able to use universal SQL statements (strings) to interact with them. SQLite is a SQL engine written in C with a C++ interface.

But... the interoperability of SQL queries was not why I thought it was a good idea. Rather the fact that the engine stores everything in a file, thus the very complex problem of file format and I/O is solved for you. http://sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: I know thats kind of pushing my options but... is there any way that I can get around this without any extra installs? Or am I pretty much left with either installing a database to all computers that will use the software or implementing a primitive database like structure myself?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 'extra installs'. The link in my comment has the source code for SQLite. You can compile it right into your program. You get an .exe in the end (or whatever executables are on your systems).

But of course nothing is forcing you to use third party code. You can design the B+ tree with your own class. Implement your own file I/O as well. But for that option you are going to need to come up with a file format that fits your needs.

Files are files, if you read the bytes the same way you wrote them... everything will be fine. Lots of work and testing IMO.